# Cocoa: how to have textfield send action (of what user typed into it) without pressing enter

Tags: cocoa, textfield, nstextfield, continuous

I have a simple cocoa application with an editable textfield text1 at the top where the user can enter stuff in as well as a non-editable textfield/label text2 at the bottom which is meant to display exactly what is typed into text1.

My problem is that I can only get text2 to update itself when the user presses enter after he types into text1. Is there any way I can have text2 automatically update itself without the user pressing enter into text1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Cocoa bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html). You could:

1. Declare an `NSString` property in your model class (which, in simple cases, could be your application delegate);
2. Bind `text1` to that string property, making sure you select ‘Continuously Updates Value’;
3. Bind `text2` to that string property.

The only step that requires code is step 1. Steps 2 and 3 can be directly configured in the nib file.

Comment: To achieve this behavior without using bindings, look in IB, under the **Control** pane, and select the **Continuous** box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want notifications on every text change, handle `controlTextDidChange:` in text field's delegate. The delegate can be any object that responds to this message, typically the window's controller is used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think the first option works. But the second option will not because text1 doesnt lose firstresponder status automatically once the user stops typing so the "end of editing" will not occur automatically as well.

Comment: btw what should text1's delegate be?

Comment: @dragoncharmer If hamstergene’s answer was the one that was most useful for you, mark it as accepted (that checkbox to the left).